# ADT is always loading the AVD

Tags: android, adt

Simply, is always loading with the "Android" sign. No error.

```
Target: Google APIs image (x86) - level 19 (and Android also)
CPU: Intel atom x86 (and ARM)
No skin (and with skin)
No cameras 
RAM 512 MB ; heap: 100 (or 30, 40, etc.)
With and without toggling 'Use Host GPU'
```

[image: Always loading]

Comment: how long have you waited?

Comment: 10 minutes ............ I tried with other configurations, but.... no

Comment: with ARM it could take even longer .. - but with intel it should be finished <10min - but to be sure wait a bit longer - that is often the problem behind this ..

Comment: AVD is notorious on its slow loading speed.

Comment: No bug report apparently

@Raptor, should I use another emulator?